# [CBAutocompleteTextFieldField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

`CBAutocompleteTextField` subclasses `NSTextField` and overridden the method:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self complete:nil];
    [super textDidChange:aNotification];
}
```

I get no warnings, however I get a run-time error:

```
[CBAutocompleteTextField complete:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xca19a50
```

Why? `NSTextField` is subclass of `NSResponder` which provides such method. Indeed I don't get warnings.

thanks

Comment: read the docs please ;) it isn't implemented

Comment: @Daij-Djan He provided all the information required to answer the question, however, so it's a "good" question.

Comment: no I really dont agree... I get this isn't popular but I would like people not to ask obvious questions... I mean.... whats with reading the docs before asking clearly documented stuff...

Comment: @trojanfoe I even up voted blinkenlight's answer!

Comment: and it is clear. not somewhere hidden

Comment: @Daij-Djan You could apply that logic to (almost) *every* question on SO.  Ultimately the solution is documented somewhere (possibly in source code).  I would consider a question "good" if it's not a duplicate and provides enough information to answer (especially without being asked for more information via a comment).

Comment: @Daij-Djan I've never meet before an "interpreted method" in the APIs before. I didn't read carefully the documentation, because I was convinced it was implemented in such class. Now I know about it, I'll be more careful in the future. Still I think it is a decent question.

Comment: declared not implemented is the word. interpreted is just a filler

Comment: @trojanfoe I consider it good if it has some value for other people and I think it doesn't. anyway I will keep down voting those questions and up voting those I find ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the method will not work unless you provide an override:

> This method can be interpreted, for example, as a request to attempt expansion of a partial word, such as for expanding a glossary shortcut, or to close a graphics item being drawn. **`NSResponder` declares but doesn’t implement this method.** (emphasis added)

Comment: I see. The reason why I'm invoking this method is just because I want the *control:textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:* be called for the suggestions drop down list. How should I implement it ?

Comment: @Patrick I am not sure how to do that (I see that you added [a question about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19860852/335858)).

Comment: Yes but I'm using a NSTextView, it is different

Comment: a textview is no NSControl IIRC

Comment: @Daij-Djan You probably wanted to reply to Patrick's comment, right? If so, check out [his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19860852/335858), this may be helpful to answering it.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yeah Daij-Djan, give me some help on the other question, I think that's the best way to implement what I need...